# to be an asset, not a liability -- what does this expression mean?

Tags: idioms

Example:

> Trump says Putin's support is **an asset, not a liability**.

What do people really mean when they say that something is an asset, not a liability? It seems like this expression has become very colloquial and you can hear it used a lot in many different contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asset is [a useful and desirable thing or quality](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/asset)

A liability is  [something that holds one back; a handicap.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/liability)

Saying something is "an asset, not a liability" is often used to counter a pronouncement that something is harmful; saying to the contrary that it is actually the reverse, a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is an "idiom", but certainly associated with the [bookkeeping.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookkeeping)

For example, if a company purchase, to say, a 10 million dollar building by borrowing from a bank, the accountant makes an entry into the [journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_entry) such as
below. ( And the company can not pay the debt worth 10 million at once but by
installments. )

Building 10,000,000 USD / Long term liability 10,000,000 USD

The left side, in the bookkeeping worlds, almost always records asset type items, such as money in the bank, cars, long term investment ( such as 10 years-maturity bond ), and so on. ( but not necessarily ), and the right side records the debt type, or capital, and accumulated incomes ( which is, incomes accumulated so far. )

So your

> Trump says Putin's support is an asset, not a liability.

means Trump is saying Putin's support is equal to money to help him not a burden aka debt to him.

Comment: Assets and liabilities are accounting terms and have non-accounting meanings as well.  "an asset, not a liability" is a common expression that doesn't at all relate to equating things to money.

Comment: Yes.But the origin dates back at least 15 century Italian renaissance, doesn't it? If you don't have any, materials such as money and buildings you own, the "common expression" would have not appeared. Rather the expression itself is the derivative from the economic activities.

Comment: I'm not sure of the history, whether the accounting usage came from common terms or the other way around.  It would be hard to believe that the usage isn't closely related, though.  But that's the individual terms, themselves.  "An asset, not a liability" is a common, non-accounting expression used in everyday language.  The meaning of the expression derives from the non-accounting meanings of the words.  I'm not sure it would even typically be used in an accounting sense (unless you're talking about students struggling to learn bookkeeping principles or "creative" accounting cheaters).

Comment: I mean, the meaning it too easy for me so that I said I am not sure it is an "idiom". If you insist such as **whether the accounting usage came from common terms or the other way around**, Merriam Unagridged says, **Origin of Assets**  -- back-formation from assets, singular, sufficient **property to pay debts and legacies, from Anglo-French asetz, from Old French asez, assez enough, from (assumed) Vulgar Latin ad satis, from Latin ad to + satis enough** — more at at, sad

Comment: I would like to say, I am sorry, answering by non native-speakers is very upsetting, am I wrong?

Comment: We're all here to learn and have fun.  :-)  In terms of the origins, the current, common, non-accounting meanings of the terms, and the modern bookkeeping meanings of the terms both evolved from the roots you describe.  My point was that while the roots of the component words relate to property and money, the expression has a life of its own.  The expression has a modern meaning based on the non-accounting meanings of the words.  (cont'd)

Comment: This is an expression where you are still able to see a related meaning from the origins of the words.  The word roots of many colloquialisms have changed so much in meaning over the centuries that you would never guess the original meanings of the words.

Comment: @fixer1234 I am not against your point about that.:)